# set layout to resize the control in java designed using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am designing the swing JFrame form using NetBeans . I am not sure about the layout setting in JFrame form .When we change the resolution of the windows the forms are not adjusted automatically

> but i want the forms and control designed on forms should be re
>   sized automatically.   How is it possible

Comment: Change the layout manager to something you can work with.  Try a few different options and even compound options. For better advice sooner, provide a small runnable example that demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the LayoutManager in by right clicking your panel. Look at this [Layout Manager guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to find which suits best for your program.

Or: For the default NetBeans Layout Manager, you need to "anchor" the components for auto-resizing. And setting them resizable, too (but it is the default).

Answer (score 0):

For any component that you want to add layout below images will guide you:

[image]

You need to choose layout that fit to your requirements.

Also you can customize the layout, to do that:

[image]

Also you can do it manualy or you can change the properties from **Customize code**.

To do that like the above image right click on the component and go to customie code(Cannot do it for `JFrame`).